# Counting all possible functions $f: A \rightarrow B$, where $f(X) \subseteq Y$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I have function $f: A \rightarrow B$ and sets $X \subseteq A$ and $Y \subseteq B$. I need to compute the number of all possible functions $f$ where $f(X) \subseteq Y$.

I know that count of all possible functions without any conditions is $a^b$ where $a = |B|$ and $b = |A|$. I think that $|X| \le |Y|$ because $F(X) \subseteq Y$ and $|F(X)| \le |X|$

Comment: Think of it as the sum two separate functions, one from $X$ to $Y$ and another from $A \setminus X$ to $B$.

Comment: Just two comments on your question. 1. You start "I have (a) function $f\colon A\to B$". But you *don't* have such a function. Rather, your goal is to count the total number of such functions. 2. You know that $|f(X)|\leq |X|$ and $|f(X)|\leq |Y|$ (if $f(X)\subseteq Y$). You can't conclude from this that $|X|\leq |Y|$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Of course, thank for your second comment! if $|X| = 100, |Y| = 5$ and every element of $X$ has value $1$ than $|F(X)| \le |X|$ and $|F(X)| \le Y$, but $|X| > |Y|$

Answer (score 2):

Your function is determined by its values on $X$ and its values on $A\setminus X$.

You have $|Y|^{|X|}$ ways of choosing the values on $X$, and $|B|^{|A|-|X|}$ ways of choosing the other values.

So your answer is
$$|Y|^{|X|}|B|^{|A|-|X|}=|B|^{|A|}\left(\frac{|Y|}{|B|}\right)^{|X|}$$

Comment: Thak you, I got it. I'm just thinking what would change if condition is $F(X) \supseteq Y$